# Blobs or white patches in lithophane

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, troubleshooting, creality-cr-10

I'm getting zits or blobs in lithophanes while printing on my Ender 3 and 10S Pro. I tried a suggestion: change resolution in mesh fixes of Cura to 0.5 (from 0.05 default). That removed the zits.

But now there are white patches as shown in the image. I reduced the resolution to 0.2 but to no avail.

Anyone else encountered this problem?

[image: Example of white patches in a lithophane print]

[image: Example of zits/blobs in a lithophane print]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bad batch of filament, with dirt or uneven thickness that wouldn't be noticeable in regular printing.  Have you tried a different spool or brand?

Comment: No. the filament is fresh out of box and is of esun cold white. so I think quality is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer now, it has to do with the resolution settings in the lithophane software I was using.

I had to set minimum resolution of the lithophane to 0.4 or 0.8 (I'm using a 0.4 mm nozzle).

**UPDATE**: sorry. The problem still persists. unable to get rid of the white patches.

Comment: What was the default resolution that wasn't working well?

Comment: It was 0.6mm...